# copy address from email search window

Tags: macos, email, search

I often have to find email addresses using the 'search' window in OSX mail.
The search function will frequently find an address for someone, and show it in the popup window below the search window.

But it often fails to find the underlying message, so I cannot open an actual existing message from the person.

And, I cannot copy from the popup window, so I can see the address I need, on my screen, but I have to write it down, and repaste it into the message I am composing.
This is beyond ridiculous.

Is there a solution?

Comment: You would normally select one of the items in the lei and then the messages related to the search will populate in the message viewer list. What happens when you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you search for an email address in the OSX Mail search bar, if you select the address from the dropdown, the mail app will automatically add the option `From:` in front of the email address in the search bar. Thus, the mail messages that show up in the left mail list will change so that only emails from the selected email address are displayed.

If you do not have any messages that are actually `From:` the email address selected, no emails will be displayed in the list. You may need to change the `From:` option in the search bar to `Entire Message` in order to see messages where a certain email address was CC'ed or if it was written in the email message text.